# Making ...rest item first while assigning value by array destructuring

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, variable-assignment, destructuring

I know that

```
var a = [12,23,132,12,3];
var [first, ...rest] = a;
```

will give `first = 12` and `rest = [23,132,12,3]`

What I would like to do is make `rest` as the first variable. Something like this

```
var a = [12,23,132,12,3];
var [...rest, last] = a;
```

which **should** give me `rest = [12,23,132,12]` and `last = 3`

But this is a wrong syntax and I will get an error that will say

```
SyntaxError: Rest element must be last element
```

I know that I can achieve this by reversing the array and then destructuring like this

```
var a = [12,23,132,12,3];
var [last, secondLast, ...rest] = a.reverse();
```

which will give me `last = 3`, `secondLast = 12` and `rest = [132,23,12]` and then I would again have to `reverse()` the rest.

I can also use indexes and directly access the array elements as well. But that is not desired.

My question is, are there any other ways to achieve what I am trying to do (using rest operators ?) ?

Comment: This is not possible due to the design of array destructuring. It takes an iterator as the input, and you don't know beforehand how many items an iterator will yield, so you wouldn't know when to stop pushing to the array and start assigning to the last targets.

Comment: Hmm, it's very much possible: `let [last, secondLast, ...rest] = [...a.slice(-2).reverse(), ...a.slice(0, -2)]`

Comment: No reverse needed for the first example: `let [last, ...rest] = [...a.slice(-1), ...a.slice(0, -1)]`, and all without mutation!

Answer (score 6):

You can use **[Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)** along with **[`Array#pop()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)** to get the `last` element, and the `rest` in your variables:

```
let [last, ...rest] = [a.pop(), ...a];
```

You can [test the results here](https://jsperf.com/destructure-last/1) and see that `pop()` is the fastest solution among other ones.

**Note:**

If we want to keep the original array intact, we just need to add the removed item

```
a.push(last);
```

- The `.pop()` call will get the `last` element from the `array` and
  affects the original `array` so there's only the `rest` of it. That
  fits exactly your needs.
- We used `a.push(last);` to retrieve the initial state of `a` array, this will avoid cloning the array or having an additional variable to clone the `a` array.

**Demo:**

```js
var a = [12, 23, 132, 12, 3];

let [last, ...rest] = [a.pop(), ...a];

a.push(last);

console.log(last);
console.log(rest);
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Just a minor comment, do `const [last, ...rest] = [ a.pop(), ...a ]`. This would prevent any mutation because of reference

Comment: Why not just `let [last, rest] = [a.pop(), a];`?

Comment: If you're mutating `a`, why even assign `rest` at all? Just use the modified `a` instead.

Comment: @MartinStone Yes, in that specific case, you are right, but normally we should clone the array before this to avoid mutating the original array.

Comment: If the `a` array is mutated we can just call `a.push(last);` after this assignement so we can get back the array to its intial state, this will avoid cloning it and having additional variables.

Comment: The temporary array is pretty inefficient. You could do just the same without destructuring: `const last = arr.pop(), rest = arr.slice();`

Comment: @Bergi Yes absolutely, it is better but it will also affect the original array, but anyway I just used destructing to match the OP requirements as he wanted it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) with negative indexes...

```
const [others, last] = [a.slice(0,-1), ...a.slice(-1)]
```

Comment: @Prasanna If you do not mind mutating array, try: `const a = [...]; const b = a.pop()`

Answer (score 1):

Per the MDN website on [destructuring assignements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_the_rest_of_an_array_to_a_variable) the rest element on array destructuring is *the remaining part of the array* so it should always be the last element.

I know you say indexes are not desired but something like `a[a.length -1]` would solve your problem

Comment: Yes no indexes. And I know rest should always be the last element, But I was looking for a work around :)

Answer (score 1):

So far I think mutating the origin array maybe the best way which is better than reversing array several times.

```js
var a = [12, 23, 132, 12, 3];
a.unshift(a.pop())
console.log(a); // [3, 12, 23, 132, 12] 

var [last, ...rest] = a;
console.log(last) // 3
console.log(rest) // [12, 23, 132, 12]
```